# Determine whether $L=\{w:|w|_a=2^n+273\text{ for }n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is regular.

Tags: automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

Given the alphabet $\Sigma=\{a, b\}$ and for the next Language $L=\{w:|w|_a=2^n+273\text{ for }n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ determine whether the language is regular.

Firstly, I think this language is regular.
And i was thinking about two options of solving this one, But i'm not not sure if i use them correctly.

Lets say i wanna write a regular expression for this kind of language:

$$b^*ab^*ab^*\dots ab^*$$

And i need to repeat it $2^n+273$ times. And altough $n\in\mathbb{N}$, The expression above gives me all the the words that are in language.

Or am i looking at this question the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any *fixed* value of $n$, the language
$$
L_{n}=\{w:|w|_a=2^n+273\}
$$
is certainly regular, and the regular expression you described will recognize it.  But the question here is whether
$$
L=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}L_n = \{w:|w|_a=2^n+273 \text{ for some } n\in\mathbb{N}\}
$$
is regular.  It's not; and the easiest way to prove it is to use the so-called [pumping lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages).  The pumping lemma says that if $L$ is regular, then all sufficiently long strings in $L$ can be written as $xyz$, where $xy^i z$ is also in $L$ for all $i\ge 0$.  In your case, consider the string $a^k \in L$, where $k=2^n+273$ for some large value of $n$.  Assuming $L$ is regular, the pumping lemma says that there's some substring $y$ (necessarily $a^{|y|}$) such that $k+(i-1)|y|=2^n+(i-1)|y|+273$ is also of the form $2^{m(i)}+273$ for all $i$.  That is,
$$
2^{m(i)}-2^n=(i-1)|y|,
$$
or
$$
2^{m(i)}-2^{m(i-1)}=|y|.
$$
But the distance between successive powers of $2$ keeps increasing, while the gap $y$ stays the same; so there can't be any such $|y|$, and $L$ can't be regular.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Regular languages are closed under intersection and under left quotients$^*$. Therefore, if $L$ was regular, then the languages
\begin{align}
  L_1 &= L \cap a^* = \{ a^k \mid k = 2^n + 273 \text{ for some $n$ }\} \\
  L_2 &= (a^{273})^{-1}L_1 = \{ a^{2^n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\} 
\end{align}
would be an infinite regular language. You can now conclude using for instance the arguments given in mjqxxxx's answer.

$(*)$ If $u$ is a word and $R$ is a language of $A^*$, the *left quotient* of $R$ by $u$ is the language $u^{-1}R = \{ v \in A^* \mid uv \in R\}\ $.